# Change pandas data frame to add max column -> maximum value for each month of the year from a data frame in pandas. How can I do this?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date, google-colaboratory

So I have a data frame structure looking like (Date, value, month, year) <- the month and year are extracted from data frame.
I want to get the maximum value of 'value' column in another column 'max', for each month of a year. There are more than one 'date' belonging to the same 'month' and 'year'.
For example,

```
Date       |value | month | year |
2013-01-03 | 13   | 01    | 2013 |
2013-01-06 | 14   | 01    | 2013 |
2014-01-03 | 16   | 01    | 2014 |
2011-01-03 | 15   | 01    | 2011 |
```

should give something like:

```
Date       |value | month | year | max |
2013-01-03 | 13   | 01    | 2013 | 14  |
2013-01-06 | 14   | 01    | 2013 | 14  |
2014-01-03 | 16   | 01    | 2014 | 16  |
2011-01-03 | 15   | 01    | 2011 | 15  |
```

Comment: Can you format the question properly please? Very hard to understand in this linear view.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I'm new on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `pd.Grouper` to group by month and `transform`:

```
df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"])
df["max"] = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key="Date", freq="M"))["value"].transform("max")

# or df.groupby(df["Date"].str[:8])["value"].transform("max")
 
print (df)

        Date  value  month  year  max
0 2013-01-03     13      1  2013   14
1 2013-01-06     14      1  2013   14
2 2014-01-03     16      1  2014   16
3 2011-01-03     15      1  2011   15
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
df['max'] = df.apply(lambda r: df[(df.month==r['month']) & (df.year==r['year'])]['value'].max(), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that *Date* column is of *datetime* type.

Use:

```
df['Max'] = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Date', freq='M')).value.transform(max)
```

I deliberately changed the column name to *Max* (starting with **capital** *M*)
in order not to "cover" the existing *Pandas* function.